# Convert DataURL (or base64) to FileList

Tags: angular

I have a bunch of DataUrl-s which I would like to convert to FileList.
According to the documentation, FileList is read-only, and such things don't/shouldn't work:

```
const fileList = new FileList()
```

So, is there a way to create `FileList` from `DataUrl`-s?

P.S. Our target is to modify the files before uploading to server.
P.P.S. Please don't suggest using `File[]` instead of `FileList` as the lib we're using doesn't accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hacky solution which seems worked fine.
Treat array of files as FileList.

Here is the code:

```
public dataUrlToFileList(dataUrls: string[], fileNames: string[]): FileList {
    const fileArray: File[] = [];

    for (let index = 0; index < dataUrls.length; index++) {
        const dataUrl = dataUrls[index];
        const fileName = fileNames[index];
        // Converting content to Blob
        const blobObject = this.dataUrlToBlob(dataUrl);
        // Converting Blob to file
        const file = new File([blobObject], fileName);
        fileArray.push(file);
    }

    // Converting array with file to filelist and passing to uploader
    return fileArray as unknown as FileList; // < -------------- MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
}

private dataUrlToBlob(dataUrl: string): Blob {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
    const byteString = atob(dataUrl.split(",")[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    const mimeString = dataUrl.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);

    // create a view into the buffer
    const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

    // set the bytes of the buffer to the correct values
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    const blob = new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString });
    return blob;
}
```